# search bar not working after session_start()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I added a search bar in maps and it was working fine but when i start session,something happened and suddenly it stop working. When i remove session,it works but with sessions it does not work.
Anyone?

My PhP code

```
<?php session_start(); 
  if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']!="") 
  { 
?> 
      <input type="text" value="" id="searchbox"> 
<?php 
  } 
  else  
  { 
    //echo "You are not supposed to be here. Please <a href='login.php'>login</a> first.";  
    header("Location:login.php"); 
  } 
?>
```

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            if (geocoder == null) {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            }
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': request.term
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var searchLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    var bounds = results[0].geometry.bounds;
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'latLng': latlng
                    }, function(results1, status1) {
                        if (status1 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results1[1]) {
                                response($.map(results1, function(loc) {
                                    return {
                                        label: loc.formatted_address,
                                        value: loc.formatted_address,
                                        bounds: loc.geometry.bounds
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var pos = ui.item.position;
            var lct = ui.item.locType;
            var bounds = ui.item.bounds;
            if (bounds) {
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at the source of the html page. It looks like php generates an error `headers were previously sent...` which makes your html code invalid.

Comment: this is html code:-<input type="text" value="" id="searchbox"><br>

Comment: Dude , PHP code is causing ERROR , u gave us HTML :)

Comment: In php i am just starting sessions. like:- session_start() @  jQuery Angry Bird

Comment: i said NO MATTER WHAT PASTE HERE YOUR INITIAL PHP CODE . AND YOU ARE NOT AT ALL COMMUNICATING : PHP WITH JAVASCRIPT CODE . OK ???? plz paste PHP code which is giving you error.

Comment: I am not having an error. Search bar does not work when i start sessions <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']!="")
{
?>
<input type="text" value="" id="searchbox">
    <?php
}
else
{
//echo "You are not supposed to be here. Please <a href='login.php'>login</a> first.";
header("Location:login.php");
}
?>

Comment: `search bar not working` Means what error , or isssue it gives ?? Any console error?

Comment: This is the problem. It is not showing any error,not in console

Answer (score 1):

I haven't even seen your code but I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it's most likely because you didn't place `session_start()` at the very top of the page. If there is `ANY` whitespace before the `session_start()` function is called, PHP will throw you an error.

Comment: i have removed all white spaces but still not working